# MvvmCross 5 Unit Test MvxNavigationService

Tags: unit-testing, mvvmcross

I am updating from MvvmCross 4.4.0 to 5.2.0 and changing to the MvxNavigationService.  The Login ViewModel was changed to use the MvxNavigationService and the IMvxNavigationService is registered for both the core and test.  The iOS application is functioning correctly.  The majority of the unit tests were fixed, but I'm having trouble with verifying the navigation completed correctly using unit test.  The trace in the unit test also navigates correctly, but MockDispatcher.Requests is returning null.  MockDispatcher.Requests should contain a value after viewModel.OnLoginAsync().Wait(); is called.  How do I go about resolving this issue?

The unit test is

```
       [Test]
    public void OnLogin_GivenValidCredentials_ThenAppRedirectsToMainPage()
    {
        Mock<IAuthenticationService> authenticationService = GetAuthenticationService();
        SetupCredentialValidity(authenticationService, true);
        var viewModel = GetLoginViewModel(null, authenticationService);
        viewModel.OnLoginAsync().Wait();

        Assert.IsNull(viewModel.ErrorMessage);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, MockDispatcher.Requests.Count, "Expected to navigate to the admin view model, but didn't");
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(HomeTabBarViewModel), MockDispatcher.Requests[0].ViewModelType);
    }
```

For the method

```
        public async Task OnLoginAsync()
    {
        IsActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
        try
        {
            if (Username == MobileAdminUsername && Password == MobileAdminPassword)
            {
                await _mvxNavigationService.Navigate<AdminViewModel>();
                //ShowViewModel<AdminViewModel>();
                return;
            }
            var authenticateResult = await _authenticationService.Authenticate(Username, Password);
            LoginResultsVisible = !authenticateResult.Success;
            ErrorMessage = authenticateResult.Message;
            if (authenticateResult.Success)
            {
                await _credentialCacheService.SetLastSuccessfulCredentials(Username, Password);
                //ShowViewModel<HomeTabBarViewModel>();
                await _mvxNavigationService.Navigate<HomeTabBarViewModel>();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            IsActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: make the test `async Task` and then `await viewModel.OnLoginAsync()`

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I changed the test method to async and used await the OnLoginAsync, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Then you need to provide more details about how your arrange the test. Show the complete test and subject under test.